# Split csv, first half to one array, second to another

Tags: java, arrays, csv

just need some quick help. I have a csv array like so:

```
String[] processes = { "256,6", "400,8", "128,4" };
```

and i want to take the first half of each index so processes[0] which is "256,6" and put the 256 in one array and the 6 in another. I know to how to just get a single line of csv into a certain array but have never needed to do this. Would I still use `split(",")`?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could still use `split(",")`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class b {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] processes = { "256,6", "400,8", "128,4" };
    String[] a1 = new String[processes.length];
    String[] a2 = new String[processes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < processes.length; i++) {
      String[] pieces = processes[i].split(",");
      a1[i] = pieces[0];
      a2[i] = pieces[1];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, quick other question though. I need them (a1 and a2 arrays) as integers and it will not let me cast them from String to int? I declared them as int arrays instead of string but nothing. tips?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.